# AJAX speed difference between localhost and remote site

Tags: ajax, performance, local

I was wondering why there is difference of over 200ms+ between AJAX request when debugging locally and live remote site.

I have two scenarios:

```
1. browser - local IIS Express - remote SQL server 
2. browser - remote IIS Server - remote SQL server
```

Scenario #2 IIS server connects SQL server on local network (192.168.1.*) so this should be no issue at all.

```
Scenario #1, Firebug AJAX response around 78ms for all requests I have done
Scenario #2, Firebug AJAX response around 350ms for all requests I have done
```

Remote SQL query to local devel IIS Express should and probably is slower than remote IIS talking to SQL on local subnet.

So where is the slowdown? I guess it has to be between remote IIS and browser but what can I do to improve this? Normal ping to that machine is around 40ms.

Thanks

Comment: What happens if you serve a hard coded list instead of checking with the SQL server? Just to rule out any network issues between the remote IIS and SQL server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have used FireBug, which is more meaningful in terms of client side profiling. You can try using Glimpse( http://blog.getglimpse.com/2011/11/01/glimpse-0-86-released/ ) for server side profiling. May be it can give you more details on whats going on in server side.